# Problema https Redirecionamento em excesso

Tags: java, glassfish

No meu sistema web, quando adiciono o código no web.xml:

```xml
<security-constraint>   
<display-name>ConstraintSSL</display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>protected</web-resource-name>
    <description/>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>

<user-data-constraint>        
  <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

O sistema fica em Redirecionamento em excesso, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa na frente do GlassFish? E.g., apache ou nginx?

Comment: Poste também as configurações relevantes sobre portas e https do  arquivo `domain.xml` ou equivalente do GlassFish

Comment: Não, apenas o glassfish mesmo, porém se eu tiro esse código e acesso https direto ele não da erro nenhum, to perdido já rs

Comment: Nesse caso alguma coisa na sua aplicação ou no servidor está redirecionando de volta para http (o que faz o request ficar em *loop*). Alguns frameworks e coisas do gênero fazem redirect, comece a varrer por aí.

Comment: A configuração do glassfish ta default, acabei de reinstalar novamente, eu tenho q alterar alguma configuração dentro dele?

Comment: Sim, você vai precisar de um certificado e rodar os comandos administrativos. A porta padrão segura do GlassFish (8181) não vem com um certificado de verdade (certificados costumam ser pagos). Comece por [essa página do manual do GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf#page=282). Além do próprio servidor de aplicação você precisa prover mais dados sobre a aplicação em si. Esse *loop* entre conexões http e https pode estar acontecendo por diversos motivos (não dá para te ajudar muito só com a `security-constraint`, essa parte parece estar ok).

Comment: certo, intendo mt pouco de servidor, vou postar o domail.xml

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44915/discussion-between-bruno-nicoletti-and-anthony-accioly).

Comment: O apache q está gerenciando o glassfish! não sabia, o pessoal da hospedagem me falou agr rs, ai muda td?

Comment: Bruno, muda. A documentação que linkei acima explica o que precisa ser feito no apache com `mod_jk` ou `mod_ajp` para habilitar acesso https://. De qualquer forma sua pergunta agora ficou completamente descontextualizada, eu diria para você dar uma lida com calma na documentação que te passei, pesquisar sobre o problema com mais calma e então retornar com perguntas mais específicas se for o caso.